# Where are Firefox languages installed on Linux?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, home-directory

I have a word list called "Swedish Dictionary" installed. Where is this dictionary physically located on my hard disk?

I'm asking about this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/g%C3%B6rans-hemmasnickrade-ordli/

Comment: All extensions are saved in [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder).